# duplicity: how to create & restore full system backup over existing files

Tags: backup, restore, duplicity

I would like to create a full system backup using the `duplicity`.

Accordingly, I created a backup of the root directory `/`, excluding `/proc`, `/sys`, `/tmp`, and `/mnt`.

However, when trying to restore the backup to the root directory, I got the following error:

```
Restore destination directory / already exists.
Will not overwrite.
```

Upon adding the `--force` option to the command, I receive a series of `[Errno 17]` errors, stating that various files already exist.

Is it the case that to restore a `duplicity` backup, the destination file system must have enough space to extract the restoration to a temporary directory? It would then be up to the user to merge the backup data and existing system?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way restoring backup with `duplicity` over existing files even with `--force` option.

Here is a discussion from [duplicity-talks](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/duplicity-talk/2008-01/msg00100.html)

> Jeremy Polen wrote:
>   I am working on restoring files from duplicity to overwrite the current
>   files that are on my server. I am getting the following message:
>
> Restore destination directory /home/jeremy/www/index.htm already exists.
>   Will not overwrite.
>
> I know there is a --force option, but it doesn't help in this instance.
>   Other than removing all the files before the restore, is there a way to
>   force files to be overwritten?
>
> ...Jeremy
>
> > Not at this point.  Perhaps --force should be extended to this case.
> >     I'll look into it.
> >
> > ...Ken

**Either the file must be deleted prior to running the script, or a different path or file name must be used.**